# Auth0 FGA inheritance way of building objects

Tags: auth0

I am trying to design Auth0 Fine Grained Authorization (FGA) model.

Below are my existing roles and permissions:

- Group_Admin can perform edit/add/update/Manage_Groups
- Group_Member can perform read/view_Groups

I want to know if it's possible to define model like this:

```
type Group
  relations
    define ManageGroups as admin
    define ManageUsers as admin
    define ViewGroups as admin or member
    define ViewUsers as admin or member    
    define member as self
    
type ManageGroups
  relations
    define add as ManageGroups   
    define edit as ManageGroups
    define delete as ManageGroups
    define view as ManageGroups
```

So basically how I can implement inheritance. Need to define separate object but while defining tuple I should be able to link all other objects wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 FGA developer here!

I hope I understood your goal correctly. I think you want something like this:

```py
type group
  relations
    define member as self
    define admin as self

    define can_add as can_manage_group  
    define can_edit as can_manage_group
    define can_delete as can_manage_group
    define can_read as can_manage_group
    
    define can_manage_group as admin
    define can_manage_users as admin
    define can_view_group as admin or member
    define can_view_users as admin or member
```

So for example:

- if you write a tuple like `(user=dev, relation=member, object=group:abc)`, then `dev` automatically gets the `can_view_group` and `can_view_users` relations.
- if you write a tuple like `(user=manager, relation=admin, object=group:abc)`, then `manager` automatically gets the `can_manage_group` and `can_manage_users` relations (and the other two). By having the `can_manage_group` relation, they also automatically get `can_add`, `can_edit`, `can_delete` and `can_read`.

You can play with this model here: https://play.fga.dev/stores/create/?id=01GDM4P2YPDYCTN5SHC9S4F5GK